# Adjective for "must not be present"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective that describes something that must be omitted/absent in a particular context?

For example, consider this software documentation that explains the relationship between two different variables:

- When `contentType = 'application/json'`, `schemaVersion` is **required** *(must be present)*.
- When `contentType = 'x-vendor/manifest'`, `schemaVersion` is **optional** *(may be present or absent)*.
- When `contentType = 'image/jpeg'`, `schemaVersion` is **_______** *(must be absent)*.

What word can be used to fill in the blank?

Comment: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Prohibited**.
See the [W3school definition](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_attribute.asp) of the *use* attribute in XML which is for exactly this characteristic :

> *use*
>
> [...] Specifies how the attribute is used.
>   Can be one of the following values:
>
> *optional* - the attribute is optional (this is default).
>   ***prohibited* - the attribute cannot be used**.
>   *required* - the attribute is required.

Comment: Ironically, w3school is widely considered to be pretty bad at teaching the languages it is supposed to teach (HTML, CSS, ECMAScript, SQL, PHP, XML, XSLT, …), but hey, at least it teaches English :-D

Comment: Ugh, technical people hate that you used w3schools. At least find something at the W3C!

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I never understood why it was so hated, I remember reading that people think it has gotten better.

Comment: @Mehrdad, please see: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @KhalidHussain did that site use to have concrete information about W3Schools? I don't see any now, but I see many people linking to it in conversations about W3Schools.

Comment: @DanGetz, you may use The Way Back Machine to check out the website at different times, here is an example: https://web.archive.org/web/20120620135916/http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 12):

**Forbidden**

> forbidden, *adj*
>
> 1 :  *not permitted or allowed*
>
> [source: Merriam-Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forbidden)

Answer (score 4):

If you don’t insist on a single word, **not allowed** works. There’s
also **disallowed**.

Note also some useful in-between words:

- … `schemaVersion` is **recommended** *(optional, but generally encouraged)*.
- … `schemaVersion` is **deprecated** *(optional, but generally discouraged)*.

Answer (score 3):

I propose the words "excluded" or "disjunct".

I believe you are referring to a case of the exclusive OR -- familiar to the computer science field as an XOR.  Philosophical mutual exclusion or mutual disjunction.

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 2):

They're good answers here already.

I thought to add, "precluded," in case it rings true too.

In the context, the meaning would be that it's prevented from possibility, which I think is the sense that's needed.

See [this listing, from Oxford dictionaries online,](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/preclude) especially the example sentences there.  For instance, "Many reports use research designs with low internal validity, precluding a complete functional analysis."

Answer (score 0):

If we change the wording slightly, we can sidestep the issue entirely by using [RFC-2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) terminology

- When `contentType = 'application/json'`, `schemaVersion` MUST be present.
- When `contentType = 'x-vendor/manifest'`, `schemaVersion` MAY be present.
- When `contentType = 'image/jpeg'`, `schemaVersion` MUST NOT be present.

[(hat tip to bishop)](/questions/368155/adjective-for-must-not-be-present#comment860152_368155)